# Segmentation fault after reading a data file into a 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, io, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault when I try to run my code to read a data file into a 2D array. Not sure if I'm not passing the array properly or I'm reading the file into the array properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void two_D_input(FILE *fp, int **arr, int* r, int* c)
{
        size_t count;
        char *line = malloc(20);
        while(getline(&line, &count, fp) != 1) {
                for(; count > 0; count--, *c++)
                        sscanf(line, "%d", *&arr[*r][*c]);
                *r++;
        }
}

main()
{
        int a, b, i, j;
        int* array[10][10];
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen("test", "r");
        two_D_input(f, &array[0][0], &i , &j);
        for(a =0; a < i; a++){
                for(b=0;b<j; b++){
                        printf("\n%d", array[a][b]);
                }
        }
        fclose(f);
}
```

The file test looks like this for now.

```
1    0
1    1
```

Comment: Where exactly is your code failing? 

Would it not be easier to use `fscanf` to extract the numbers directly from the file?

Comment: The `int **arr` you have in your function is not compatible with the `int* array[10][10]` in the caller.

Comment: Also you've got problems with the way `r` and `c` are initialized.

Comment: Also I don't think the `count` returned by `getline` is what you want to loop over.

Comment: It just popped into my eyes that you do not free the memory allocated in `two_D_input`.

Comment: I bet you get lots of warnings when you compile.  Also, int* array[10][10]; declares a 2d array of int pointers.  You probably want a 2d array of ints.  int array[10][10]; is probably the right declaration.  Also, you don't need to pass r and c as pointers into two_D_input since you don't do anything with them after the function returns.

Comment: `count` is the initial size `getline` allocates to hold `line` (default `120-bytes`), you really should use the `return` from `getline` not `count`.

Comment: You pass uninitialized `count` to `getline`, this causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @SteveSummit That is correct, but also irrelevant. What is passed to the function is `&array[0][0]` which has a type `int**`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void two_D_input(FILE *fp, int arr[][10], int *r, int *c){
    size_t count = 0;
    char *line = NULL;

    *r = *c = 0;
    while(getline(&line, &count, fp) != -1) {
        char *readPos = line;
        int readLen = 0, col = 0;
        while(col < 10 && 1==sscanf(readPos, "%d%n", &arr[*r][col], &readLen)){
            readPos += readLen;
            ++col;
        }
        *c = col;//It is necessary all the same number of columns
        ++*r;//or (*r)++;
    }
    free(line);
}

int main(void){
    int a, b, i, j;
    int array[10][10];
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("test", "r");
    two_D_input(f, array, &i , &j);
    for(a = 0; a < i; a++){
        for(b = 0; b < j; b++){
            printf("%d ", array[a][b]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Scary how close those were.

Comment: I forgot to the number of rows check.

Comment: Yes, but it was fun seeing all the other similarities. I'd had an earlier appointment, then dabbled with the answer a bit, and then we both posted within a minute of one another. Beyond the timing, I guess there really are a few standard ways of doing things in C, because the crux of the solutions were almost identical.

Answer (score 2):

It took a bit to understand what you are trying to do. If I understand correctly, you want to declare a static array of `M x N` size, and then have `two_D_input` fill up to `M x N` elements returning the actual *row* and *col* values filled through pointers `r` and `c`.

There is nothing wrong with doing it that way, but you will have to enforce reading (or initializing) the same number of columns per row so that the value for the number of columns read doesn't end up pointing to uninitialized values. You also must protect against reading beyond the limits of your array.

While you can read each row of data with `getline` before parsing each line of data into integer values, it is just a easy to use a statically declared buffer and `fgets` in `two_D_input`. (it also eliminates the need to `free` the memory allocated by `getline`)

Putting all the pieces together, you can write you `two_D_input` function similar to the following:

```
enum { NROW = 10, NCOL = 10, MAXC = 256 };
...
void two_D_input (FILE *fp, int (*arr)[NCOL], int *r, int *c)
{
    char buf[MAXC] = "";          /* temp buffer to hold line */
    int tmp = 0, tmpc = 0;        /* temp int and column val  */
    *r = *c = 0;                  /* initialize row, col ptrs */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read line into buf */
        char *p = buf;
        int n = 0;    /* read int into tmp, get offset in buf */
        while (tmpc < NCOL && sscanf (p, " %d%n", &tmp, &n) == 1)
        {          /* while cols < NCOL & value read from buf */
            arr[*r][tmpc++] = tmp;      /* assign array value */
            if (tmpc > *c) *c = tmpc;   /* update colum width */
            p += n;                 /* update p for next read */
        }
        if (*c != tmpc) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid column count.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        (*r)++, tmpc = 0;         /* increment row, reset col */
        if (*r == NROW)          /* check against max row val */
            break;
    }
}
```

(don't forget `(*r)++` increments the value pointed to by `r`, `*r++` increments the pointer `r`.

Putting it all together you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for exit */

enum { NROW = 10, NCOL = 10, MAXC = 256 };

void two_D_input (FILE *fp, int (*arr)[NCOL], int *r, int *c)
{
    char buf[MAXC] = "";          /* temp buffer to hold line */
    int tmp = 0, tmpc = 0;        /* temp int and column val  */
    *r = *c = 0;                  /* initialize row, col ptrs */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read line into buf */
        char *p = buf;
        int n = 0;    /* read int into tmp, get offset in buf */
        while (tmpc < NCOL && sscanf (p, " %d%n", &tmp, &n) == 1)
        {          /* while cols < NCOL & value read from buf */
            arr[*r][tmpc++] = tmp;      /* assign array value */
            if (tmpc > *c) *c = tmpc;   /* update colum width */
            p += n;                 /* update p for next read */
        }
        if (*c != tmpc) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid column count.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        (*r)++, tmpc = 0;         /* increment row, reset col */
        if (*r == NROW)          /* check against max row val */
            break;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int array[NROW][NCOL] = {{0}};
    int i, j, r = 0, c = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    two_D_input (fp, array, &r, &c);
    printf ("\n read (%d x %d) array\n\n", r, c);

    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose (fp);

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) printf (" %2d", array[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input Files**

```
$ cat dat/a2d.txt
1    0
1    1

$ cat ../dat/10by10.txt
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/a2dfscanf <dat/a2d.txt

 read (2 x 2) array

  1  0
  1  1

$ ./bin/a2dfscanf <../dat/10by10.txt

 read (10 x 10) array

  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Look it over, and let me know if you have any questions.